# Auto fill the excel column

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working with a Macro that generates a column that is the sum of the other two columns in a table. However, the table's row number is not always the same, so when I run the Marco for a table that has less rows, some extra cell in that column will give 0, is there a way I can get rid of them?

The Marco code is here:

```
 Sub sum()
    '
    ' sum Macro
    '
    ' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+s[![enter image description here][1]][1]
    '
        Range("AV1").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "AV"
        Range("AV2").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-6]+RC[-4]"
        Range("AV2").Select
        Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("AV2:AV84")
        Range("AV2:AV84").Select
        ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-30
        Range("AV1").Select
    End Sub
```

The result is here:
[image]

Please help thank you.

Comment: You have '84'  FIXED in you macro, why do you think there are 'extra cells' are created? And if you think 3 seconds longer, what will be the solution ?

Answer (score 4):

Without all the `Select`...

```vb
Sub sum()
    Dim  lr as long
    With Activesheet
        .Range("AV1").Value = "AV"
        lr = .Cells(.rows.count, "AR").End(xlup).Row 'last occupied row in Col AR
        .Range("AV2:AV" & lr).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-6]+RC[-4]"
    End with
End Sub
```

Useful to review this: [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: Thank you for your help!